# Equivalent of $(A+B)^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I am working on inverse matrices and I have raised a problem about the inverse of the sum of two matrix. I have searched for quite a while but still could not find an answer. Does anyone know what is $(A+B)^{-1}$? Is it just $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ or something else?

Comment: If you multiply $(A+B)(A^{-1}+B^{-1})$, it's clear it cannot be true in general.

Comment: Note that even for scalars, one does not have $(a + b)^{-1} = a^{-1} + b^{-1}$.However, if your question is whether the inverse distributes across sums, the answer is no. The answer to your question is that if $(A+B)^{-1}$ exists, it is the unique matrix $M$ such that $M (A + B) = (A+ B)M = I$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the sum can be non-invertible for instance $A=I$ and $B=-I$.

Assuming that's not the case there is [The woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)

Comment: Woodbury matrix identity would give $$(A+C)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}(A^{-1}+C^{-1})^{-1}A^{-1}$$ Is it easy for calculations ?